# Error in Form Submisson with Rails and Hotwire

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hotwire-rails

I am running rails 6.1 with hotwire. I am creating a login form take email and password and then redirect to the store_index path. However, I am running into this error- Error: Form responses must redirect to another location. I have tried the following
things but getting the same error,

1. Using  `format.html { redirect_to store_index_path}`
2. I commented out everything in the create function and added puts "Hello". However, i still got the same error.

I an confused now, any help

```
  <%= form_with url: retailer_log_in_path, class: 'box'  do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label 'email:', class: "label"%><br>
        <%= f.text_field :email, class: "input" %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label 'password:' ,class: "label"%><br>
        <%= f.password_field :password, class: "input" %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.submit 'Log In', class: "input" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

session controller.rb

```
def create
        retailer = Retailer.find_by(email: params[:email])
        if retailer.present? && retailer.authenticate(params[:password])
            session[:retailer_id] = retailer.id 
            redirect_to store_index_path
        else
            flash.now[:alert] = 'Invalid email or password'
            render :new
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want to use turbo drive form submission you have to return 4xx or 5xx response code for validation errors from your controller:

eg

```rb
render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
```

In your code, it should look like this:

```rb
    def create
        retailer = Retailer.find_by(email: params[:email])
        if retailer.present? && retailer.authenticate(params[:password])
            session[:retailer_id] = retailer.id 
            redirect_to store_index_path
        else
            flash.now[:alert] = 'Invalid email or password'
            render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
    end
```

You can find more info in Turbo documentation https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/drive#redirecting-after-a-form-submission

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not use turbo_frame_tag to wrap the form.

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag "post" do %>
  <%= render 'form', post: @post %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This isn't right. OP wants the form submission to hit `format.html` in their controller, but a turbo_frame_tag would make it hit a `format.turbo_stream` block instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your form to work like it did pre-Hotwire, add `local: true` to your form declaration. In other words, change your form declaration from this:

```
form_with url: retailer_log_in_path, class: 'box'
```

to this:

```
form_with url: retailer_log_in_path, class: 'box', local: true
```

According to [the Rails form helper docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#how-do-forms-with-patch-put-or-delete-methods-work-questionmark), `form_with` defaults to using the parameter `remote: true`. This activates Javascript on the form, and the error is because the Javascript is expecting a particular (asynchronous) response; if you add `local: true` to your `form_with` declaration, the form submission will not be asynchronous, and the error should go away.